# Problema al tratar de activar los cambios en WebLogic Server después de haber borrado un archivo .war

Tags: oracle, weblogic

Estoy tratando de activar los cambios después de haber borrado un archivo 
   .war en el servidor WebLogic, pero al presionar el botón Activar cambios 
    me sale la siguiente leyenda:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Revisando el log me dice lo siguiente :

```
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org/apache/xalan/processor/TransformerFactoryImpl
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
at javax.xml.transform.FactoryFinder.getProviderClass(FactoryFinder.java:125)
at javax.xml.transform.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:182)
at javax.xml.transform.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:250)
at javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.newInstance(TransformerFactory.java:101)
at weblogic.management.provider.internal.ConfigReader.convert(ConfigReader.java:99)
at weblogic.management.provider.internal.ConfigReader.<init>(ConfigReader.java:70)
at weblogic.management.provider.internal.ConfigReader.<init>(ConfigReader.java:64)
at weblogic.management.provider.internal.RuntimeAccessDeploymentReceiverService.handleConfigTreeLoad(RuntimeAccessDeploymentReceiverService.java:967)
at weblogic.management.provider.internal.RuntimeAccessDeploymentReceiverService.updateDeploymentContext(RuntimeAccessDeploymentReceiverService.java:599)
```

Soy nuevo en el manejo de WebLogic Server por lo cual se me complica solucionar este problema  y por ello acudo a ustedes comunidad.

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Weblogic solía usar una carpeta stage donde ponía todo lo que desplegabas en él independiente de la carpeta con el war que realmente quedaba desplegado. Posiblemente borraste a mano lo que debías eliminar a través del manager.

Comment: @Alfabravo es correcto, pero como podría solucionar este problema ? de antemano gracias

Answer (score 3):

Podría ser que te falte añadir xml-apis.jar y xercesImpl.jar ya que indica un fallo de que no encuentra la clase. Lo he visto por http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/xsltc_usage.html#classpath donde dice "The xalan.jar contains support for both Xalan-Java processors. You can use the JAXP javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory property (see "Calling XSLTC with the JAXP API" below) to select which processor to use: the Interpretive or the Compiling processor.

To use XSLTC, simply put xalan.jar, serializer.jar, xml-apis.jar, and xercesImpl.jar on your classpath." Básicamente indica que para que funcione añadas los .jar que solicita. Espero que sirva de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que tirar el servidor que tiene desplegado ese war. Una vez esté abajo, desde el administrador web de weblogic, desinstala o borra la aplicación que lleva el war que has borrado.
Una vez hecho eso, levanta el servidor. Con eso debería solucionarse el problema.